# Thread only loops once

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

ive been thinking about this for hours and im not closer to an solution!
My thread just stops looping when im fetching a message from an server for some reason, and works perfectly when im not doing it.

This works and prints refreshing every second:

```
 public class ChatRoom extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Runnable {
        private Thread t = new Thread(this);

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.chatroom);

                Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
                send.setOnClickListener(this);

                Intent receiver = getIntent();
                String host = receiver.getStringExtra("Host");
                int port = receiver.getIntExtra("Port", 4456);


                try
                {
                    socket = new Socket(host, port);
                    this.receive = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
                    this.send = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                } 
                catch(IOException ioe) { System.out.println(ioe); }
                t.start();


            }

            public void run()
            {
                String message = "";

                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // message = receive.readLine(); BufferedReader
                        t.sleep(1000);
                    } 
                    //catch(IOException ioe)            { System.out.println(ioe); }
                    catch (NullPointerException npe)    { System.out.println(npe); } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e)      { System.out.println(e);   }

                    System.out.println("Refreshing...");

                }
            }
```

And when i use my commented code, it actually works and i get a message from the server but it loops just once! Why is that?

```
Output:
Server Message
Refreshing...
```

I get no Exception or errors, but i had an error before with some similar code that said that i cant change UI on other threads. So ive been looking at some runOnUiThread but it didnt make it better, and i dont know why it should :(

Comment: How are you starting this thread? I assume 't' is the thread? More information needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) blocks until a newline character is received. If there is no newline in your receiver stream it will block forever.

Comment: Thanks, cant believe i didnt realize this >.<

Answer (score 3):

A few things here:

- Swap from System.out.println("string"); to Log.d("tagname","string"); then look on DDMS for output lines.

I don't think you're creating a thread properly, and you certainly aren't providing any interface to kill it, which may cause issues when you test it. I would separate the thread into a new file, say `NameOfThread`:

```
//File "NameOfThread"
public class NameOfThread extends Thread{
//any fields you want here to mess with e.g.
private String message;
private boolean running;


public NameOfThread(){
    message = "";
    running = true;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    while(running){
        //do stuff
    }   
}

public void setRunning(boolean run){
    running = run;
}
```

}

```
//When you want to call it
NameOfThread varThread = new NameOfThread();
varThread.start();

//when you want to kill the thread
varThread.setRunning(false);
```

You may think 'why bother with this whole `running` variable junk, I don't need it.' but how else will this thread end gracefully? There is another method of killing the thread properly, which is using `InterruptedException` and your cleanup code goes there, but that's just an alternative.

Try doing this first, then you'll need to sort out the message itself (the method you're using currently isn't great since `readLine()` will block until a line is received (meaning you'll get "Refreshing..." when you get a new line rather than once per second.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the inspiration! Just did a filthy solution to try out some stuff. But the main problem was the readLine which blocks just as you pointed out, so i can now continue :)

Comment: No problem. Your next problem I forsee will be setting the text you've retrieved in your thread to a TextView. For this, you need to use AsyncTask (Android will not permit threads to update UI elements unless they are from the native thread so things like onTouch, onClick onPause onCreate etc). You -can- add extra methods to a bog-standard Thread to give this functionality using Looper/Handlers, but AsyncTask is easier.

Answer (score 0):

You're surely getting some exceptions thrown, you just can't see them cause you're trying to print them on the standard output, which is missing on Android. Your exception is handled correctly and the code finishes. To properly get the exception information use `Logs`, or just throw a `RuntimeException`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not getting any exceptions since i can see my prints. However if i try to set text into my TextView, it says:11-06 16:41:22.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5041): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.